# How can I calculate "feature vector" of spam texts via application of WEKA?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka, feature-extraction

I want to implement Mail Filtering; classifying e-mails as spam or legitimate (Textual Categorization) by machine learning in application of WEKA.

How can I get "feature vector" of dataset via aplication of WEKA? This vector should include 100 words of spam which are highest frequency and highest weight.

Data Set : http://www.dt.fee.unicamp.br/~tiago/smsspamcollection/smsSpamCollection.arff

Answer (score 1):

I didn't use WEKA, but I did the same thing using Matlab a year a go as part of the machine course offered by coursera by Dr. Andrew NG from Stanford in the 7th week. 
To create the feature vector you can search the Email to see if each of the words exists or not. Then the feature vector will be a vector of zeros and ones where a one means that the corresponding word exists and zero means it doesn't.